# Native Urdu Speakers saying "I'll I'll" when speaking English

Tags: etymology, accent

I have a number of Indian colleagues who are fluent in English (but Natively spoke Urdu or Hindi) and I've noticed a trend to stutter the word "I'll" when they speak it, as in:

> I'll I'll look into that.

I love language, and especially the etymology of how languages from multiple cultures combine into a common language, so I've become curious as to the nature of this.  Is there something in one of the base language grammar or patterns here that leads to this behavior?

Comment: I have talked to many native Hindi speakers and a few Urdu (I think the common spelling is with 'U' ;) and never noticed that stuttering is more common with them. Does it just happen with *I'll*? Do you think it's involuntary like actual stuttering? Or more of a way of saying "I'm not absolutely sure about this, but I guess..."?

Comment: Seems to be just with I'll, I've noticed it among 4 or 5 different speakers.

Comment: Native Hindi speaker here, and literally no Hindi speaker I know does that.